# Center a Textview only in steps of the width of its monospace letters

Tags: android, textview, center, monospace

I am trying to create a fake LCD display.

It should exist of some normal text, showing some data, and a background, faking that LCD look:
[image: img01]

I wrote this xml, aligning 3 TextViews on top of each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_linearLayout_footer_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dashboard_bottom_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="28dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_heading2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.15"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="88888888888888888888888888888888888"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="28dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_heading3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.15"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="28dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Works fine for some cases, but now look what happens if the textlength of the topmost View changes:
[image: img02]

The Views aren't properly aligned any more, as only the upper View changed its width and therefore is centered again.

What I am asking is, **is there a possibility to center a TextView, but only in steps of the width of one letter of the used `monospace`-font**

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to use a `TextView` for each char with a drawable that represent the two layers "`8`" and "`X`" as background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView_heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/char_0"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="28dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/lcd_char"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/char_1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="28dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/lcd_char"/>

    <!-- ... -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/char_n"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="n"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="28dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/lcd_char"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, If you prefer, you can also use three horizontal `LinearLayout` for each layer in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/char_0"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textSize="28dip" 
            android:background="@drawable/lcd_char"/>

        <!-- ... -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textView_heading2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/char_8_0"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:alpha="0.15"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textSize="28dip" 
            android:background="@drawable/lcd_char"/>

        <!-- ... -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textView_heading3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/char_X_0"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:alpha="0.15"
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textSize="28dip" 
            android:background="@drawable/lcd_char"/>

        <!-- ... -->
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

So in onCreate() method you can retrieve all led chars in this way:

```
TextView[] lcdChars = new TextView[3/*lcd size*/];
for (int i = 0; i < lcdChars.length; i++) {
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("char_"+i, "id", getPackageName());
    lcdChars[i] = (TextView) findViewById(resID);
}
```

And then set the text you want with a method like this:

```
private void setLCDText(char[] chars){
    for (int i = 0; i < lcdChars.length; i++) {
        if(i < chars.length){
            lcdChars[i].setText(chars, i, 1);
        }else{
            lcdChars[i].setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, with that code, the text has a left alignment. But, it is no big deal to make it centered. The disadvantage in this solution is, that the number of digits isnt variable any more, can't depent on the screen size. I will look into it, if I could use it, maybe with some modifications.

Comment: @walla: If you want you can add `TextView`s to `LinearLayout` at runtime, according to screen size. 
Another solution is to have different XML layouts with a different number of digits, [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) as Android wants: for example you can have `res\layout-sw600dp\lcd_layout.xml` with 5 digits for 7” tablets and `res\layout-sw720dp\lcd_layout.xml` with 8 digits for 10” tablets.